# How to calc sum(saldo_out)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  two tablel   first  tables' name **SVOD** and it is as follows  :

| code_coa | code_filial | code_currency | last_oper_day | saldo_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20602 | 00856 | 000 | 14.11.22 | 10000000 |
| 20602 | 00856 | 000 | 10.12.22 | 50000000 |
| 20602 | 00856 | 840 | 10.04.23 | 600000 |
| 20602 | 00413 | 978 | 28.12.22 | 10000 |
| 20602 | 00413 | 000 | 19.04.22 | 10000000 |
| 20602 | 00856 | 000 | 30.12.23 | 10000000 |
| 20602 | 00856 | 000 | 10.04.23 | 10000000 |
| 20602 | 00412 | 000 | 30.12.23 | 10000000 |
| 20602 | 00856 | 000 | 18.04.23 | 10000000 |
| 20602 | 00654 | 000 | 19.04.23 | 10000000 |

and name the second  **day_operational** and it is structured as follows

| oper_Day | day_status |
| --- | --- |
| 10.04.2023 | 1 |
| 11.04.2023 | 1 |
| 12.04.2023 | 1 |
| 13.04.2023 | 1 |
| 15.04.2023 | 1 |
| 16.04.2023 | 1 |
| 17.04.2023 | 1 |
| 18.04.2023 | 1 |
| 19.04.2023 | 0 |

i want to sum the saldo_outs in `svod.last_oper_Day` less than each **day_operational.oper_day**
for example :

| oper_Day | code_filial | code_currency | sum_saldo_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.04.23 | 00856 | 000 | 10000000 |
| 11.04.23 | 00856 | 000 | 50000000 |
| 12.04.23 | 00856 | 840 | 600000 |
| 13.04.23 | 00413 | 978 | 10000 |
| 14.04.23 | 00413 | 000 | 10000000 |
| 15.04.23 | 00856 | 000 | 10000000 |
| 16.04.23 | 00856 | 000 | 100000000 |
| 17.04.23 | 00412 | 000 | 35000000 |
| 18.04.23 | 00856 | 000 | 100000000 |

warning: I randomly selected the value of `sum_saldo_out` from the table above

Comment: Please post your current code and describe what is the issue with it